# Curl "Connection refused" error?

Tags: php, curl

I have a server which runs the following php code:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://somewebaddress"); 
... 
... some curl options 
...
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I test the above code from my local machine at home, curl_exec($ch) returns the correct response.

When I test the above code from my server, curl_exec($ch) returns an error:

```
* About to connect() to somewebaddress port 9003 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0*
```

What can the "Connection refused" error mean?
Why on my local machine the code works, but on my server there is the error "Connection refused"?

I contacted the owner of somewebaddress and he told me that he opened the firewall for my ips (the local machine and my server). Can it be that the firewall on my server is blocking somewebaddress and that's why the error "Connection refused" is risen?

So, given the error "Connection refused", does this mean that the problem is on my end, or on the other end (somewebaddress)? If on my end, what could be the causes? If on the other end, what could be the causes?

Comment: If you can confirm that the target port 9003 is open (if you can connect from your local machine it is) it is most probably a firewall issue, but it is impossible to say on which end.

Comment: What exactly about the firewall is the issue? Do I need to open some port on my end? Or do I need to somehow allow the ip of somewebaddress to connect to my server?